# Selecting a subset of circles using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When creating circles using D3, is it possible to create a group such that they can be selected at a later stage? For example, if circles are created using the following approach:

```
var dataset = [   [ 30, 50, 20],
                  [ 100, 50, 20],
                  [ 150, 50, 30]];


//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",  200)
            .attr("height", 200);

// generate circles 
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d){
                return d[0];
                })
   .attr("cy", function(d){
                return d[1];
                })
   .attr("r",  function(d){
                return d[2];
                });
```

Can I tag the circle created from the first array element with `circle1` and the second two circles as `circle2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

absolutely - update the class attribute dynamically based on the data index:

```
.attr("class", function(d,i) {return i == 0 ? "circle1" : "circle2";});
```

then use the assigned classes for selecting elements:

```
d3.select(".circle1"); //first circle
d3.selectAll(".circle2"); //second and third circles
```

Comment: Should be `(i == 0)` as the index is 0-based.

Comment: Is `i` a counter that keeps track of what position the circle constructor is in the data array?

Comment: pretty much, per the documentation: "..then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum `d` and the current index `i`, with the `this` context as the current DOM element."